# Displaying image name with html decimal code and URL encoded

Tags: php, html

I build web application to manage spare parts for client,it comes with manual book as standard their part-id.
 I checked its part-id are unique numbers. Storing records using MYSQL v5.5.16 and web interface using PHP v5.3.8.

As client requirement, they want to have spare parts image to be listed in folder. Basically, when user inputting record and upload a image, i renamed the image based on part-id stored into database and copied an uploaded image to folder.

Yes, it work well when user displaying images (part-id: 241203, 299301 ... etc). When part-id come with 1/8S40003, as you know image name couldn't consist with some characters (/ \ : * ? " < > |).

I also put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` between `<head>` tags and `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on the top of page.

I simplified, just encode '/' sign to **html decimal code** ->  `&#047;`.
Storing image name into database seem work well, uploading image work 100%, i also checking image manually inside folder,

but when displaying image with

```
<img src='../Images/Spare parts/1/8S40003.png' />
```

Web browser automatically decoded it into path directory ('/'), but i checked a tag on 'view source', it written with `<img src='../Images/Spare parts/1&#047;8S40003.png' />`.

Even using *htmlentities*, html_entity_decode, *htmlspecialchar*, htmlspecialchars_decode doesn't work and make it worse to convert '&' sign into `&amp;`

I found another way, by using *urlencode* from php, by convert '/' -> %2F and append the rest of number.

```
<img src='../Images/Spare parts/1%2F8S40003.png' />
```

I checked a tag on 'view source', it written similar with above but it doesn't give an solution.

Anyone, who ever had experienced with this problem before or ideas would be appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: show me the destination folder path where you store your images

Comment: Try using `rawurlencode($imgName)` - http://php.net/rawurlencode

Answer (score 0):

As chirag indicated with his reply, the problem is that the file system does not accept some characters like `/` as well. So you probably stored the images with `&#047;` in the file name.

So to use that messed up image name in the url, you need to use: `urlencode(str_replace('/','&#047;',$id))`.

It probably would be better if you came up with a more solid scheme of generating file names from part ids, for example by applying rawurlencode to the file name. this would result in applying url encoding twice when refering to the image in html links, but it be solid: `urlencode(rawurlencode($id))`

Comment: Yes it might give us more solid scheme, but it will be difficult to web browsers to read image name as its twice encoding and image won't appear as we expected. Thank you about your explanation, but using `rawurlencode($id)` works like charms! Thanks a lots guys =)


I tested $id consist `&#047;` and `%2F` and applied with rawurlencode(), image appear on pages, it might be happen, cause web browser decode anything encoded characters appear on pages once.=)